# Attempting to copy and paste multiple sections of a table to new word doc, keeps pasting new tables in first cell

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

So I am trying to copy and paste multiple columns of an excel database into a word document. Every time it completes a "round" it keeps the cursor in the first cell and therefore messes up the formatting. I am attempting to make the cursor scroll out of the previous table to create a new table below. the problematic code is indicated in 'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document

I have tried

```vb
    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=54
```

But it gives an error

Here is my full code:

```vb
Sub ReportGen()

'ROUND 1

Dim myValue As Variant
Dim atbl As Excel.Range
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim aWordTable As Word.Table

'Define whos info you need
myValue = InputBox("Who are you meeting with?")

'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False

'Copy Range from Excel
  Sheets("Stage Gate (Open)").Select
  ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$AL$25").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=myValue
  Set atbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stage Gate (Open)").Range("C6:C10,a6:a10,b6:b10,e6:e10")


'Create an Instance of MS Word
  On Error Resume Next

    'Is MS Word already opened?
      Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")

    'Clear the error between errors
      Err.Clear

    'If MS Word is not already open then open MS Word
      If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")

    'Handle if the Word Application is not found
      If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "Microsoft Word could not be found, aborting."
        GoTo EndRoutine
      End If

  On Error GoTo 0

'Make MS Word Visible and Active
  WordApp.Visible = True
  WordApp.Activate

'Create a New Document
  Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add

'Copy Excel Table Range
  atbl.Copy

'Paste Table into MS Word
  myDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteExcelTable _
    LinkedToExcel:=False, _
    WordFormatting:=False, _
    RTF:=False

'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document
  Set aWordTable = myDoc.Tables(1)
  aWordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
  myDoc.Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=54

'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True

'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

'ROUND 2


Dim btbl As Excel.Range
Dim WordTable As Word.Table

'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False

'Copy Range from Excel
   Sheets("Stage Gate Support (Open)").Select
  ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$AL$25").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=myValue
  Set btbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Stage Gate Support (Open)").Range("C3:C10,a3:a10,b3:b10,e3:e10")


'Make MS Word Visible and Active
  WordApp.Visible = True
  WordApp.Activate


'Copy Excel Table Range
  btbl.Copy

'Paste Table into MS Word
  myDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteExcelTable _
    LinkedToExcel:=False, _
    WordFormatting:=False, _
    RTF:=False

'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document
  Set bWordTable = myDoc.Tables(1)
  bWordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
  Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=54

'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True

'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

'ROUND 3


Dim ctbl As Excel.Range
Dim cWordTable As Word.Table

'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False

'Copy Range from Excel
   Sheets("Bermondsey (Open)").Select
  ActiveSheet.Range("$A$6:$AL$25").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=myValue
  Set ctbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Bermondsey (Open)").Range("C6:C10,a6:a10,b6:b10,e6:e10")

'Make MS Word Visible and Active
  WordApp.Visible = True
  WordApp.Activate

'Copy Excel Table Range
  ctbl.Copy

'Paste Table into MS Word
  myDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteExcelTable _
    LinkedToExcel:=False, _
    WordFormatting:=False, _
    RTF:=False

'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document
  Set cWordTable = myDoc.Tables(1)
  cWordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
  Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=54

EndRoutine:
'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True

'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```

Comment: When you get an error, please remember to report the error message and the line of code that triggers it...

Comment: This has been asked before. See, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54393978/how-to-place-one-table-directly-after-another/54397093#54397093 - the key is to set the table.range to a range object, collapse that, then insert the new table at the collapsed range. If the two tables should not merge together, insert a paragraph mark, first.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. Note that nothing ever gets selected, which makes the code far more efficient. As coded, each table is output on its own page.

```
Sub ReportGen()
Dim atbl As Range, btbl As Range, As Range
Dim WordApp As Object, myDoc As Object
Dim myValue As Variant

  'Define who's info you need
  myValue = InputBox("Who are you meeting with?")

  'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False

  'Create an Instance of MS Word
  On Error Resume Next
  'Is MS Word already opened?
  Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
  'Clear the error between errors
  Err.Clear
  'If MS Word is not already open then open MS Word
  If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  'Handle if the Word Application is not found
  If Err.Number = 429 Then
    MsgBox "Microsoft Word could not be found, aborting."
    GoTo EndRoutine
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0
  'Make MS Word Visible and Active
  WordApp.Visible = True

  'Set Excel Ranges
  With Sheets("Stage Gate (Open)")
    .Range("$A$6:$AL$25").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=myValue
    Set atbl = .Range("C6:C10,a6:a10,b6:b10,e6:e10")
    Set btbl = .Range("C3:C10,a3:a10,b3:b10,e3:e10")
  End With
  With Sheets("Bermondsey (Open)")
    .Range("$A$6:$AL$25").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=myValue
    Set ctbl = .Range("C6:C10,a6:a10,b6:b10,e6:e10")
  End With

  'Create a New Document
  Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
  With myDoc
    'Copy Excel Table Range
    atbl.Copy
    'Paste Table into MS Word
    .Range.Characters.Last.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document
    .Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior 2 'wdAutoFitWindow
    .Range.InsertAfter Chr(12)
    'Copy Excel Table Range
    btbl.Copy
    'Paste Table into MS Word
    .Range.Characters.Last.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document
    .Tables(2).AutoFitBehavior 2 'wdAutoFitWindow
    .Range.InsertAfter Chr(12)
    ctbl.Copy
    'Paste Table into MS Word
    .Range.Characters.Last.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document
    .Tables(3).AutoFitBehavior 2 'wdAutoFitWindow
  End With

  Set atbl = Nothing: Set btbl = Nothing: Set ctbl = Nothing
  Set myDoc = Nothing: Set WordApp = Nothing

EndRoutine:
  'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  'Optimize Code
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```